# Align Text Of Different Sizes Vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 pieces of text. One is aligned left, the other to the right. The one on the left is bigger than the one on the right. How can I get them to align vertically centered to each other?

[image]

```
<section role="outer" class="bg-cover section section-fullWidthContent position-relative first">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div>
                <h1 class="section-title">Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <a href="" class="text-md-right"><h1 class="xsmall-title">See All</h1></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

```
.section-title {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.xsmall-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.section-title {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.xsmall-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section role="outer" class="bg-cover section section-fullWidthContent position-relative first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h1 class="section-title">Title</h1>
      <a href="#" class="xsmall-title">See All</a>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an align-items-center on the outer div that holds both element

```
<section role="outer" class="bg-cover section section-fullWidthContent position-relative first">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div>
                <h1 class="section-title">Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <a href="" class="text-md-right"><h1 class="xsmall-title">See All</h1></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

[image: I tried it on Codepen]

I added the property `align-items:baseline` to the wrapping class, that seems to do the job.